# How can I change my avatar back from my custom one to the default one with a random pattern?

Tags: support, gravatar

Lets say I have changed my avatar to something else, then how can I revert back to same old random avatars generated by SO sites?

Comment: Actually, your avatar (gravatar) is not random, but generated from a hash of your email address, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to gravatar com, login and there is option "Do not use this image". Click it and confirm. It will take to some time to update your one to randomized, though. However, I see you have normal generated gravatar right here